# Merging multiple columns into a single column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Suppose I have a dataframe as follows

```
  C1 C2
0  A B
1  C NaN
2  E F
3  G H
```

how can I merge the two columns into one using pandas

**output**

```
  new
0  A
1  B
2  C
3  NaN
4  E
5  F
6  G
7  H
```

Comment: How did D suddenly appear?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. D was to be replaced with NaN. @jpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use DataFrame constructor with converted `DataFrame` to numpy array:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'new':df.values.ravel()})
```

Or [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.stack(dropna=False).reset_index(drop=True).to_frame('new')
print (df)
   new
0    A
1    B
2    C
3  NaN
4    E
5    F
6    G
7    H
```

Comment: Sure, once my rep goes above 15 i will.